# In Rails, what is the standard way to turn on code-caching for Model, View, Controller, all of them, or individually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-caching

Is it true that the standard way to say "cache all Model, View, Controller code" when running the Rails server, by using the following line in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

and for don't cache any of them:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

and to "selectively" cache any one of them, use the above `false` line, and in `config/environment.rb`:

```
config.load_once_paths += %W(  #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models  )
```

which will only cache the Model code.  And to cache Controller code or View code, just add either

```
#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/controllers
```

or

```
#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/views
```

to inside the `%W{  }`.  For example, if we are only developing the Views (HTML and CSS), then there is no need to reload
Model and Controller code when running the server, so set `load_once_paths` for Models and Controllers, 
and just let the View code load every time?  (is there docs that talk about this?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no documentation that explains this in detail, but you can read about rails configuration here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

As for your question, You are absolutely correct :).

use `config.load_once_paths` to cache selectively ( Obviously with  `config.cache_classes = false`   )

And use  `config.cache_classes = true`  to cache everything